# How to change multiple column names at one time?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to change three column names of a data frame at one time.

When I worked with one column name change, my code worked well:

```
    names(df)[names(df)== "name1")] <- "name12"
```

But when I tried to change three column names in one command, error occurred:

```
    names(df)[names(df)= c("name1, "name2", "name3")] <- c("name12", "name22", "name32")
```

I would be grateful if anyone could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple == check, checks for eqaulity. So 1 == 1 is true. However if you want to check multiple values, you have to use a different operator (I know, weird right?!) essentially in the line 
`names(dmodel112)= c("name1, "name2", "name3")` you try to compare an entire vector (the colnames of your dataframe) against a vector.

Beter is `names(dmodel112) %in%  c("name1, "name2", "name3")`

that way you check against every option in the vector c("name1", "name2", etc)

Answer (score 5):

If you know the column numbers you could simply do:

```
names(df)[1:3] <- c("name12", "name22", "name32")
```

A safer approach (because order doesn't matter) is to use a named `list` (or vector using `c`), `match` it with the current names and `na.omit`. The list should be filtered for items that actually exist `%in%` the current names.

```
lst <- list(FOO="gear", BAR="fAiL", BAZ="am", QUX="mpg")

names(mtcars)
# [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
   
names(mtcars)[na.omit(match(lst, names(mtcars)))] <- names(lst)[lst %in% names(mtcars)] 

names(mtcars)
# [1] "QUX"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "BAZ"  "FOO"  "carb"
```

Appears to be robust against things like:

```
lst <- list(none='sense', li='st'); lst <- NULL; lst <- NA
```

Answer (score 3):

The "data.table" package has a function `setnames` that sets names by reference and allows for replacing only specific names in an "old -> new" type of syntax.

```
df <- data.frame(name1 = 1:2, name2 = 3:4, name3 = 5:6, V1 = 7:8)
df
#   name1 name2 name3 V1
# 1     1     3     5  7
# 2     2     4     6  8

library(data.table)
setnames(df, c("name1", "name2", "name3"), c("name12", "name22", "name32"))
df
#   name12 name22 name32 V1
# 1      1      3      5  7
# 2      2      4      6  8
```

To understand the "sets names by reference" part, you can use `tracemem()` to see what's happening with direct assignment in comparison to using `setnames()`:

```
tracemem(df)
# [1] "<000000001A58CDB8>"
names(df) <- letters[1:4]
# tracemem[0x000000001a58cdb8 -> 0x000000001c571670]: 
# tracemem[0x000000001c571670 -> 0x000000001c571478]: 
df
#   a b c d
# 1 1 3 5 7
# 2 2 4 6 8

setnames(df, LETTERS[1:4])
df
#   A B C D
# 1 1 3 5 7
# 2 2 4 6 8
tracemem(df)
# [1] "<000000001C571478>"
```

---

Note that you can use `setnames` in two ways:

```
## Replace specific names by specific values
setnames(your_data_frame, names_to_replace, replacement_values)

## Replace all names
setnames(your_data_frame, new_names)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `which` to get the column indices like so:

```
colnames(df)[which(colnames(df) %in% c("name1, "name2", "name3")] <- c("name12", "name22", "name32")
```

Comment: In fact which() is not needed. A simple logical vector as returned from %in% itself is enough and it's actually faster. which() will convert into a numerical vector of indices instead, which is not needed here